# How to define a generic data type as Message in actix

Tags: rust, rust-actix

Is there a way to write this code with `#[derive(Message)]` and `#[rtype(result = "...")]`.

```rust
pub struct MyMsg<T> {
    data: T
}

impl<T: 'static> Message for MyMsg<T> {
    type Result = Result<MyMsg<T>, Error>;
}
```

I tried this but the compiler complains about the required lifetime bounds.

```rust
#[derive(Message)]
#[rtype(result = "Result<MyMsg<T>, Error>")]
pub struct MyMsg<T> {
    pub data: T,
}
```

Comment: *"To be more clear"* - didn't make it any clearer to me ;)

What are the errors you are facing? Please show us your attempt and what errors it gives. It's hard to guess your mistake without seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use `anyhow`, because otherwise `Result<..., Error>` wouldn't make much sense. (as `Error` is a trait, not a type)

Then, I don't understand your problem, it just works:

```
use actix_derive::Message;
use anyhow::Error;

#[derive(Message)]
#[rtype(result = "Result<MyMsg<T>, Error>")]
pub struct MyMsg<T: 'static> {
    pub data: T,
}
```

If you expand that with `cargo expand`, you can see that you get:

```rust
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2021::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
use actix_derive::Message;
use anyhow::Error;
#[rtype(result = "Result<MyMsg<T>, Error>")]
pub struct MyMsg<T: 'static> {
    pub data: T,
}
impl<T: 'static> ::actix::Message for MyMsg<T> {
    type Result = Result<MyMsg<T>, Error>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it seems like if I define the lifetime specifier when I'm defining the `MyMsg` struct , It's gonna work.